# what is replacing drawingbrush in windows universal projects

Tags: xaml, windows-10-universal

I have the following code in wpf, which I want to use in Windows Universal,

```
<Border>
    <Border.Background>
        <DrawingBrush Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,10,10" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0,0 L10,0 10,10, 0,10Z" Brush="White" />
                    <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0,10 L20,10 20,20, 10,20 10,0 0,0Z" Brush="Gray" />
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

But I get the following error: 
DrawingBrush is not supported in a Windows Universal project.
What this does is the background for transparent color with gray and white squares.  Any one knows a solution for how to redo it without using an image?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't the option in UWP without using an image with `ImageBrush`, but someone like @FilipSkakun could come along and prove me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/drawing-shapes#path) in UWP like this

```
<Path Stroke="White" 
  StrokeThickness="1"
  Data="M0,0 L10,0 10,10, 0,10Z" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, greatly appreciated.